# Linked List of Structures - How to Edit a Data

Tags: c, linked-list

This is my structure and the node I add. my insert function is okay but when I try to add the Course_Student data later, by searching for the student's uId and add the data to that specific node; my list is deleted and it shows nothing . and then when I add another node the Course_Student data is shown in an odd way.
How can I add My Course_Student data to one specific node later ?

```
typedef struct stdnt Student ;
typedef struct crs_std Course_Student;

struct crs_std{  
    int crs_code;
    char name[20];
    float grade;
    int unt;
};

struct stdnt { 
       char firstname[20];
       char lastname[20];
       Course_Student a[10];
       unsigned long long uID;
       int year;
       float avg;
};

struct Linked_list_Student{

    Student s;
    Node_s *next_s ;
```

This is the function I use to add data to my linked list after inserting data .

```
void Select_Course(NodePtr_s *startPtr_s, Course_Student cs[10], int id){
    int i;
    NodePtr_s prevPtr_s;
    NodePtr_s currPtr_s;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        if((*startPtr_s)->s.uID == id){

            (*startPtr_s)->s.a[i].crs_code = cs[i].crs_code;
            strcpy((*startPtr_s)->s.a[i].name,cs[i].name);
            (*startPtr_s)->s.a[i].unt = cs[i].unt;

        }

        prevPtr_s = (*startPtr_s);
        currPtr_s = (*startPtr_s)->next_s;

        while(currPtr_s != NULL){

            if(currPtr_s->s.uID == id){

                currPtr_s->s.a[i].crs_code = cs[i].crs_code;
                strcpy(currPtr_s->s.a[i].name,cs[i].name);
                currPtr_s->s.a[i].unt = cs[i].unt;

        }

        prevPtr_s = currPtr_s;
        currPtr_s = currPtr_s->next_s;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: don't do manipulation on `NodePtr_s *startPtr_s`, this is your __head__ pointer. use a temporary variable for that.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
```

...what is n?  It appears n is probably a global set to 10, for looping through cs?  If so, then your approach is not the best.  It seems you are:

```
foreach element in cs
    find the correct student record
    add that element from cs to the student record
```

But it sounds like all elements in cs should get added to the same student record?  If so, you should really be doing:

```
find the correct student record
foreach element in cs
    add that element to the student record
```

Please verify that is what you are trying to achieve then I or someone else here can help you with the correct algorithm.

Also, please make sure your indentations are correct so people can easily read your code:

```
    while(currPtr_s != NULL){

        if(currPtr_s->s.uID == id){

            currPtr_s->s.a[i].crs_code = cs[i].crs_code;
            strcpy(currPtr_s->s.a[i].name,cs[i].name);
            currPtr_s->s.a[i].unt = cs[i].unt;

    }

    prevPtr_s = currPtr_s;
    currPtr_s = currPtr_s->next_s;
    }
```

should be

```
    while(currPtr_s != NULL){

        if(currPtr_s->s.uID == id){

            currPtr_s->s.a[i].crs_code = cs[i].crs_code;
            strcpy(currPtr_s->s.a[i].name,cs[i].name);
            currPtr_s->s.a[i].unt = cs[i].unt;

        }

        prevPtr_s = currPtr_s;
        currPtr_s = currPtr_s->next_s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `startPtr_s` just to initialize your loop and use `Node_s` for your temp variable:

```
void Select_Course(NodePtr_s *startPtr_s, Course_Student cs[10], int id)
{
  Node_s *current = NULL;
  int i;

  /* iterate on each node in your list */
  for (current = *startPtr_s; current != NULL; current = current->next_s) {
    if (current->s.uID != id) continue;

    /* On each node update your data */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      current->s.a[i].crs_code = cs[i].crs_code;
      strcpy(current->s.a[i].name,cs[i].name);
      current->s.a[i].unt = cs[i].unt;
    }
  }
}
```